# How can update the value of a variable passed to an InlineButton

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm recently on StackOverflow.

Now I write a bot on Telebot API, I'm trying to make a dynamic keyboard with user likes and dislikes. I want the number of clicks on a button to be displayed on it. To do this, their values are written to the database (I use sqlite3).

Initially, the values are displayed correctly, but the new value of the variable appears only after restarting the bot.

What function or method should I use to update values without restarting?

```
import telebot
import sqlite3 as sql
import config
from telebot import types

connection = sql.connect('lind.sqlite')
q = connection.cursor()
#q.execute('''CREATE TABLE lind (id int auto_increment primary key, like int, norm int, diz int)''')
connection.commit()

teal1 = int(0)
tean1 = int(0)
tead1 = int(0)

q.execute("INSERT INTO lind (like, norm, diz) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')"%(teal1, tean1, tead1))
connection.commit()

q.execute("SELECT * FROM lind")
connection.commit()
re = q.fetchone()
az = re[1]
azz = re[2]
azzz = re[3]

q.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


photo = 'AgADAgAD-6wxG7agqUrFbpkcDO9ste__tw8ABAEAAwIAA20AA4X1BgABFgQ' #'ШУ Гуюаньчунь'}},

def keyboard_reaction():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Like {like}'.format(like=az), callback_data='tea1like')
    but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Norm {norm}'.format(norm=azz), callback_data='tea1norm')
    but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='DizL {diz}'.format(diz=azzz), callback_data='tea1diz')
    keyboard.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
    return keyboard

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first(message):
    startmenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    startmenu.row('GO!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!✋', reply_markup=startmenu)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == 'GO!':
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption='Бин Дао Юань Ча', reply_markup=keyboard_reaction())

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inline(c):

    if c.data == 'tea1like':
        connection = sql.connect('lind.sqlite')
        q = connection.cursor()
        q.execute("SELECT like FROM lind")
        connection.commit()
        re = q.fetchone()
        az = re[0]
        az += 1
        q.execute("UPDATE lind SET like ='%s'"%(az))
        q.close()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, show_alert=True, text='You Clicked Like. You number {nl}'.format(nl=az))
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Бин Дао Юань Ча', reply_markup=keyboard_reaction(like=az))


    elif c.data == 'tea1norm':
        connection = sql.connect('lind.sqlite')
        q = connection.cursor()
        q.execute("SELECT norm FROM lind")
        connection.commit()
        re = q.fetchone()
        azz = re[0]
        azz += 1
        q.execute("UPDATE lind SET norm ='%s'"%(azz))
        q.close()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, show_alert=True, text='You Clicked Norm. You number {nn}'.format(nn=azz))
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Бин Дао Юань Ча', reply_markup=keyboard_reaction(norm=azz))

    elif c.data == 'tea1diz':
        connection = sql.connect('lind.sqlite')
        q = connection.cursor()
        q.execute("SELECT diz FROM lind")
        connection.commit()
        re = q.fetchone()
        azzz = re[0]
        azzz += 1
        q.execute("UPDATE diz SET like ='%s'" % (azzz))
        q.close()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, show_alert=True, text='You Clicked Dizlike. You number {dn}'.format(dn=azzz))
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Бин Дао Юань Ча', reply_markup=keyboard_reaction(norm=azzz))


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `az, azz, azzz` variables in `inline()` function are diferent to `az, azz, azzz` variables in `keyboard_reaction()` function. You sloud initialize this variables in `inline()` as a global varible.

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inline(c):
    global az
    global azz
    global azzz
    ...
```